# Cant establish connection to a wireless device from a wired device on the same network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet

I have a ZTE F660 router provided by the ISP. My PC is connected through wire/ethernet cable to the router. Recently I was tinkering with a microcontroller known as NodeMCU ESP 8266 commonly used for simple IoT projects, which can connect to WiFi and do cool stuff. Following a simple tutorial online I was able to run a simple HTTP server on it. **However, the problem is the webserver is accessible through mobile devices using the private IP (192.168.1.x), but when I try to access the same through PC (wired connection) there is no response.** The IP of my pc is 192.168.1.2 and the microcontroller is 192.168.1.3
I have already tried :

1. Disabling firewall in windows and in the router.
2. Making sure WiFi isolation is disabled.
3. Pinging the device, in which I got timeout error.

Comment: can you ping 192.168.1.1 from both  pc and web server? Do both  pc and web server  have the same mask, and gateway?

Comment: Can ping 192.168.1.1 from both PC and the NodeMCU. And yes, both the PC and web server have the same mask(255.255.255.0) and gateway(192.168.1.1)

Comment: Have you got wireless isolation enabled on your router?

Comment: No, as I mentioned in the question, WiFi Isolation is disabled.

Comment: Well it certainly looks like the router has isolation enabled in spite of you turning it off. The focus point here should be the router.

Comment: Is there any way to disable it through the command line? Maybe the website isn't communicating with the router!